# Flexbox toolbar with a ton of nesting

Tags: css, navigation, flexbox

I am trying to build a flexbox type container with a search and filters and buttons. I am having trouble getting the desired behaviour. The `toolbar-container` class is the main flex container, which holds `search-bar` and `filter-group` as the top-level flex-items. I am getting confused as to how approach setting up `filter-group` as a nested flex-container to which the desired behavior is to push the `buttons` to the end of the row (far right, equivalent to `float: right`) and give the filters the largest amount of space, wrapping below as the window resizes but maintaining the positions of `search` and `buttons` on either side. I have tried using the below css the seperate the fitlers from the buttons but there filters and buttons stay grouped together like this:

**`search-bar`**-**`filters`**-**`buttons`**---------------------------------------------------

Below is desired layout, with only the filters wrapping to the space below when the space decreases.

**`search-bar`**-**`filters`**-----------------------------------------------------**`buttons`**

```
<div class="toolbar-container">
    <div class="search-bar"></div>
    <div class="filter-group">
        <div class="filters"></div>
        <div class="buttons"></div>
    </div>
</div>


.toolbar-container {
    display: flex;
}

.search {

}

.filter-group {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.filters {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.buttons {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `flex: 1` for you `.filter-group` to take all remaining space. Demo:

```css
.toolbar-container {
  display: flex;
}

.filter-group {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1; /* new */
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.filters {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar-container">
  <div class="search-bar">Search bar</div>
  <div class="filter-group">
    <div class="filters">Filters</div>
    <div class="buttons">Buttons</div>
  </div>
</div>
```